# XAML Binding to a CollectionViewSource property on a ViewModel

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have a simple ViewModel like:

```
public class MainViewModel {
    ObservableCollection<Project> _projects;
    public MainViewModel() {
        // Fill _projects from DB here...
        ProjectList.Source = _projects;
        ProjectList.Filter = ...;
    }

    public CollectionViewSource ProjectList { get; set; }
}
```

I set the window's DataContext to a new instance of that ViewModel in the constructor:

```
public MainWindow() {
    this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

Then in the Xaml I am attempting to bind the ItemsSource of a ListBox to that ProjectList property.

Binding just ItemsSource like so doesn't work:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectList}" ItemTemplate="..." />
```

But if I first rebase the DataContext this works:

```
<ListBox DataContext="{Binding ProjectList}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="..." />
```

Shouldn't the first method work properly? What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting your data from the DB synchronously or asynchronously ?

Comment: synchronously, beside if it was a race condition then the second method would not work either...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are using `CollectionViewSource` you need to bind `ItemsSource` to `ProjectList.View` instead of `ProjectList`. That should solve your problem.

Comment: So I guess I can't duplicate my problem like that either... I've updated the question with what the ViewModel "really" looks like.

Comment: See my updated answer. I'm not exactly sure why CollectionViewSource works this way, but its the way I've always had to work with them.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. This is the first time I've used a CollectionViewSource. I ended up making the property type `ICollectionView` and in the getter I return the `View` property from a private CollectionViewSource. That way I don't need to worry about binding to `.View` which would break if I change the collection type of that ViewModel property in the future.

Answer (score 0):

From what you provided the first method should perfectly work. Devil lurks somewhere in details.

PS: Maybe you didn't specify implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in sake of post size, but be careful in production. It's very easy to get a [memory leak](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938416/en-us) if you don't implement it.

Comment: Yes, it actually does implement that interface. Call it a test case if you will.