# Binding a CollectionViewSource to ObservableCollection

Tags: .net, binding, collectionviewsource

Cannot bind the CollectionViewSource

DocProps is a public property

```
public ObservableCollection<DocProp> DocProps1
```

DataContext is self

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"
```

This works

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DocProps1}">
```

I cannot wire up a CollectionViewSource to sort
This does not even get DocProps1

```
    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <ListBox.ItemsSource>
            <Binding>
                <Binding.Source>
                    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Path=DocProps1}">
                        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name" />
                        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                    </CollectionViewSource>
                </Binding.Source>
            </Binding>
        </ListBox.ItemsSource>
```

How do I bind a CollectionViewSource to a public property?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It will work this way:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <ListBox.DataContext>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Path=DocProps1}">
    </CollectionViewSource>
  </ListBox.DataContext>    
</ListBox>
```

This article [XAML Binding to a CollectionViewSource property on a ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009454/xaml-binding-to-a-collectionviewsource-property-on-a-viewmodel) has some explanations of this behaviour