# wpf collectionviewsource in viewmodel or xaml code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, collectionviewsource

I am in this dilemma and hope someone can help me out

sorry I cannot paste code here as company block posting here.

i am trying to use collectionviewsource in xaml. i tried two ways, static resource and cvs.source. first one works pretty well but limitation is i can only find resource from code-behind. but control ui and disaplay ui not on same view, i don't know how to trigger sort/filter
so i move to second option, i put cvs in view model with properties exposed to both ui. but i got this famous error "trying to change ui not owned by this thread"

so generally what is good practice of where to put csv. i checked many places suggesting second option http://www.xamlplayground.org/post/2009/07/18/Use-CollectionViewSource-effectively-in-MVVM-applications.aspx and [XAML Binding to a CollectionViewSource property on a ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009454/xaml-binding-to-a-collectionviewsource-property-on-a-viewmodel) but seems no one mentioned ui thread ownership issue. am I doing something really stupid

thanks

Comment: `CollectionViewSource` is intended to be used in XAML. You're looking for a `CollectionView` in the ViewModel.

Comment: Why can you 'only find [a Static]resource from code-behind'? Surely the whole point of declaring a `StaticResource` is that you can then refer to it in XAML?

Comment: @Sheridan, i have two ui and two code-behind. how i can route event/command from one ui to another ui? most of sample code i see, code-behind is very light.

Comment: @HighCore, you are right. you can even get collectionview without declaring collectionviewsource in xaml or behind-code. there is default view for each collection object

Answer (score 3):

If you keep having problems with threads, use a `Dispatcher`:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
  new Action(() => /* modify the collection */));
```

Or use `EnableCollectionSynchronization` method, which is new in WPF 4.5 and will do the same for you:

```
private static object syncObject = new object();
//...
BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(yourCollection, syncObject);
```

Read more about it [here](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/24/wpf-4-5-part-7-accessing-collections-on-non-ui-threads/).

Comment: +1 for the coding example of EnableCollectionSynchronization.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, i will take a look at EnableCollectionSynchronization. but i don't like to introduce new technique each time i hit a problem as i believe this is very common usecase and I am newbie in wpf. just want to have basic right